# Как работает метод flush() в spring-data-jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jpa, transaction, flush

Есть проект на стеке `spring-boot-2.0.3`, `spring-data-jpa-2.0.3` и `postgresql-9.5.13`. Всего три класса: `@Entity`, `@Repository` и основной класс. В БД одна таблица с двумя колонками: `id` и `name`.

Добавляю в эту таблицу `100 000` записей в цикле и замеряю время исполнения запроса, включая или отключая метод `flush()` класса `EntityManager` через каждые 100 записей.

Ожидаемый результат: при включенном методе `flush()` время выполнения запроса должно быть значительно меньше, чем при выключенном.

Фактический результат: противоположные показания.

---

**Вопрос:** Что я делаю не так?

---

**Структура проекта:**

[image: структура проекта]

---

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/twofold
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

---

**User.java**

```java
package twofold.data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public User() {}

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_id_seq", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "users_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + id + "; name: " + name + ";";
    }
}
```

---

**UserRepository.java**

```java
package twofold.data;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

---

**Application.java**

```java
package twofold;

import twofold.data.User;
import twofold.data.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner addUsers() {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Transactional
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                long incoming = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
                    userRepository.save(new User(i + "_name"));
                    if (i % 100 == 0) {
                        entityManager.flush();
                        entityManager.clear();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-incoming));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если в двух словах, то метод `flush()` производит запись сохраненных данных непосредственно в СУБД.
При нормальном исполнении (без `flush`) у вас данные в БД попадают не сразу, а после того, как завершится транзакция (при настройках по умолчанию).
То есть ваш код за эти 100 000 итераций порождает около 1000 походов в БД для сохранения данных, что увеличивает время выполнения метода.